# How To add gridview cell automatically

Tags: c#

Gridview cell add automaticall by loop and value set on gridview cell

```
 int txt1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
 int txt2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

 for (int i = txt1; i < txt2 + 1; i++)
 {
      MessageBox.Show(""+i);
      for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count+1; j++)
      {
         dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["id"].Value = i.ToString();
      }
 }
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("id", "ID");
 }
```

I'm trying like this check this link.

[Image Link Click Here And See What i'm trying](http://postimg.org/image/am5nepg29/)

Comment: why you are not returning data table and giving datasouce to gridview?

Comment: how will you explain or post code

Comment: what do you want to achieve? What doesnt work in your code? Do you want to add rows right after you wrote values into textboxes or what?

Comment: rows does not add user input 254 to 258 in this conditioned rows and columns add and show data like my pic but its not work rows and columns not add data will shown only one row and one columns and all data replace each other

Comment: my english is not good hope u can understand my words

Comment: @user2491383 see the sample code you can acheive with giving datasource.

Comment: @Altaf Sami what is serach?

Comment: see edited answer you can add more columns also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First loop is not required, why are you doing it?

You just need to add rows, not columns, so you have to do something like:

```
 table.Rows.Clear(); //to ensure the table does not contains any rows
 table.Rows.Add(txt2-txt1);
 int i = txt1;
  for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
      {
         dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["id"].Value = i.ToString();
         i++;
      }
```

Comment: if txt1 is 254 and txt2 is 258 your code will be 10 to 11 rows add and same columns all value is 258 is shown

Comment: :O its work but value not set properly m setting value like this 2,3,4,5 but ur code last values set on all cells sorry its my code

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
  int txt1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
  int txt2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("RollNo");
  dt.Columns.Add("TotalRolls");
  dt.Columns.Add("RollsFrom");
  dt.Columns.Add("RollsTo");

  for (int i = txt1; i < txt2 + 1; i++)
  {
      object[] row = { i, (txt2 - txt2), txt1, txt2};
      dt.Rows.Add(row);            
  }
  return dt;
}
```

do this in your cs file on search button click etc.

```
gridView.DataSource = GetData();
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Search is the method that is getting data from db, this will be in your data access layer, see edited answer.

Comment: ok then you can do like this, and can add more columns you want.